# How to fix height of select option in angular

Tags: html, angular, ionic2

I have 100 options in select tag but the height of select option is very large I want to reduce the height of select option. I used size=10 but its not working for me.

**HTML**

```
<ion-col size-md="6">
                <select size=10 class="ci-sec-head ci-mr-15" id="years" [(ngModel)]="calendar.year" (change)="renderCalender()" style="border:transparent; width: 50%;">
                <option *ngFor="let yr of years" [value]="yr.value" [selected]="yr.isSelected">{{yr.text}}</option>
                </select>            
            </ion-col>
```

Comment: try `size="10"` this

Comment: Already try out but not working